# Fragment Lifecycle - webservice call in onStart() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, okhttp

In order to display some Web service information inside a fragment A, I am doing the call to the WS in onStart() method.

If an activity has several fragments, the webservice call  will be executed onBackPress() too if from example I'll navigate from fragment B back to fragment A.

Is there a way I could stop this?
I don t want to execute any WS calls on back press.

Comment: "I am doing the call to the WS in onStart() method" -- that should be crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Please do network I/O on a background thread. "Is there a way I could stop this?" -- detect whether or not you have your data, and do not call out to the Web service if you already have your data.

Comment: @CommonsWare I m using okhttp library.

Comment: I depends on how frequent you update your data. If you want to get data only on the first load of fragment, use onCreate() method or every time your fragment loads use onResume().